# Wireless 802.11n slow on some days when 802.11g works well

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I recently changed internet provider and rented a D-Link N 300 Router. On most days everything works well. However on some days the internet connection on my new laptop that has Intel Centrino Wireless-N 130 network adapter get really terrible (usually on Friday and Saturday). At first I thought that the problem was with provider, but now I find out that my old laptop that does not support 802.11n (only 802.11g) has excellent internet connection (at the same time when the new laptop struggles).

How can I troubleshoot what is causing this problem - the laptop network adapter or the router? Is there some setting for network adapter to force using 802.11g?

My laptop is running Windows 7, if that matters.

EDIT: After running inSSIDer I found more than 20 APs and so it seems that Dave's answer is at least pointing in the right direction. Here's a picture of the channels (my AP is CGATES_...). [image: AP survey 2.4 Channels results] I'm not sure if I'm looking at the right stuff yet, but hopefully I'll be able to help some help from my provider after the weekend or figure out how to configure the router myself.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would do is a simple site survey and see if there are other APs in the area that are using the same channel.  If your AP is set to automatically switch, it can conflict sometimes and not others.  You may need to do the survey more than once as APs may turn on or change channel.
You may be able to select a channel that is unused.

Comment: And the tool to do this is [inSIDDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/).

Comment: Dave, @sblair, thanks! I believe that channel conflict is probably the cause of my problem. Now I have to figure out how to best remedy that.